# Align image in CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my HTML page coded like this:

```
<div class="nav_icons" id="github">
          <a href="http://github.com/kida001"><img src="imgs/github.png" alt="github" /></a>
        </div>
```

in CSS I have this:

```
.nav_icons a img {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 60px;

}
```

Yet no matter what I put for the vertical-align I can't get it to the top. If I do align="top" inline CSS for the image on the HTML page it works. How can I do this in the CSS class? The page I'm editing is currently local, otherwise I'd link to it. Thank you!

Comment: Provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I believe the image also needs display: inline-block; for vertical align to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"id" is more powerful than "class". So, you can use it like this:

```
#github a img {
vertical-align: top;
padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the dimension of #github and put the image as "background-image" in CSS. It could be the easy way to align the image.